# Documentation of Eclipse-PlatformFilter

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing plug-ins for an eclipse RCP application. One of the plug-ins needs OS-specific implementations.

It seems that plugin fragments would meet my needs (see e.g. [1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119058/platform-specific-code-in-eclipse), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166666/how-do-we-create-os-specific-plugins)).

I think I understand how fragments work now, but apart from the sparse documentation of fragments, there doesn't seem to be any documentation of the `Eclipse-PlatformFilter` header in the manifest file.

According to [4](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html), it has to be *a valid LDAP filter string*, but that doesn't explain any more than the two examples I found on the internet (the MacOS cocoa one and the windows 32bit one).

So my question is:

**Is there any documentation of the Eclipse-PlatformFilter header?**

(If there isn't, can anybody tell me the valid values for the header?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is an example of the Eclipse-PlatformFilter header:

> Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32)
>   (osgi.arch=x86))

Here are possible values for each osqi.* property

Operating system - osgi.os:     win32, linux, macosx, aix, solaris, hpux, qnx

Windowing system - osgi.ws:         win32, motif, gtk, photon, cocoa

Processor architecture osgi.arch:   x86, x86_64, ia64, ia64_32, ppc, PA_RISC, sparc

Example above would activate fragment only when Eclipse is running on Windows 32bit.

If you want to activate when running on Windows 64bit you would use:

> Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32)
>   (osgi.arch=x86_64))

on linux 32bit

> Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=gtk) (osgi.os=linux)
>   (osgi.arch=x86))

on linux 64bit

> Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=gtk) (osgi.os=linux)
>   (osgi.arch=x86_64))

on macOS 64bit and PowerPC

> Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=cocoa) (osgi.os=macosx)
>   (|(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.arch=ppc)))

You can pick at eclipse fragments to figure out filers for all supported platforms.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. Is it possible to specify multiple values, e.g. x86 and x86_64? I'm still curious where these values come from, though (LDAP, Java, Eclipse,...). BTW, there is only a text field for specifying the platform filter in the fragment's `MANIFEST.MF` (latest eclipse photon for eclipse committers), that's why I asked for the possible values.

Comment: @danzel The LDAP syntax allows an 'or' operator using `|` - one I found is `(& (osgi.ws=cocoa) (osgi.os=macosx) (|(osgi.arch=x86)(osgi.arch=ppc)) )` - Cocoa on macOS with either x86 or ppc architectue.